# Want to get array from method in java

Tags: java

I am building a java program, which does the following functions:

1. get input from user
2. place intergers into array
3. add 10000 to each integer in array.

The problem: can't get the array from plus(int arr[]), and print them inside main().

```
public class inputToArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        insertToArray(num);
    }


}
public static void insertToArray(int getNum) {

    int array[] = new int[10];

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {

        array[i] = getNum;
    }

    plus(array);

}
public static int[] plus(int arr[]) {

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

        arr[i] += 10000; 
    }

    return arr;
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You would have to return something to main to be able to print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made some mistakes :

- your create a new array for each new int, and you want at the end to have all of thme in the same ? not very easy
- you use arrays in method, but you never take them back

---

To match with your requirements :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int array[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int val = scan.nextInt();
        array = insertToArray(val, array, i);   //"please insert val at place i in array"
    }
    array = plus(array);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static int[] insertToArray(int getNum, int arr[], int place) {
    arr[place] = getNum;
    return arr;
}

public static int[] plus(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] += 10000;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

---

Just put something more compact :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array[i] = 10000 + scan.nextInt();       
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Comment: I actually want to pass every integer to another method and there place them all in an array. Dear azro

Comment: @Adam not really performant, but here we go, look and accept if it's ok ;)

Comment: can you explain the following, insertToArray(val, array, i).

Comment: @Adam it just put the value `getNum` at the place `place` of the array, an then return this array, because you need to use the same